# Slow-running File parser

Tags: c#, performance, parsing

I've got a method that parses a file.  I take all the words and add them to a `SortedSet`.  Every word contains a list of `Lines` that contain said word.  Words are not strings but a class I created:

```
class Word : IComparable<Word>
{
    public Word()
    {
        Lines = new List<Line>();
    }
    public string WordStr { get; set; }
    public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Word other)
    {
        return string.Compare(this.WordStr, other.WordStr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

And the method that parses the file (I suspect I am not doing something properly here):

```
private void AddFile(string path)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9\\s\\']");
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
        if (!fi.Exists || Files.Contains(path.ToLower())) //File does not exist or file already indexed
        {
            return;
        }
        Files.Add(path.ToLower());
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
        string file = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string saniFile = regex.Replace(file, "");
        string[] saniLines = saniFile.Split(new char[]{'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int lineNo = 1;
        foreach (var l in saniLines)
        {
            Line line = new Line(l, path, lineNo);
            string[] words = l.Split(' ');
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                Word w = new Word();
                w.WordStr = word;

                if (Words.Contains(w, new WordComparer())) //Set already contains the word
                {
                    Word wordToAdd = (from wors in Words where wors.WordStr.ToLower() == w.WordStr.ToLower() select wors).First();
                    if (!wordToAdd.Lines.Contains(line))
                        wordToAdd.Lines.Add(line);
                }
                else
                {
                    w.Lines.Add(line);
                    Words.Add(w);
                }
            }
            lineNo++;
        }
    }
```

I have the exact same functionality working in C++ and it's orders of magnitudes faster.  So is there something I am doing incorrectly?  What if I used a `SortedDictionary` instead of a `SortedSet` for the words?  Then the key could be the string that is the word and the value would be the list of lines that contain that word.

For reference, a 618KB text file takes a few seconds to parse and index in C++.  It's taking me minutes to do it in C#.

Comment: I would change the `foreach` to a `for` if you can. I was trying to do a lot of small things really fast (few thousand in less than a second) and `foreach` added a great deal of overhead (causing it to run more than 1 second). I don't know if that would apply in a longer running situation. But I do know in general, `for` will be faster than `foreach`. I've seen benchmarks on SO where it's upwards of 5x faster in some situations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your instincts are basically right that maybe a dictionary of some sort could help. Let's look at some key lines of your code.

```
foreach (var l in saniLines)
{
    Line line = new Line(l, path, lineNo);
    string[] words = l.Split(' ');
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        Word w = new Word();
        w.WordStr = word;

        if (Words.Contains(w, new WordComparer())) //Set already contains the word
        {
            Word wordToAdd = (from wors in Words where wors.WordStr.ToLower() == w.WordStr.ToLower() select wors).First();
            if (!wordToAdd.Lines.Contains(line))
                wordToAdd.Lines.Add(line);
```

I see 5 nested loops here. If you step through the code, you'll see them, too. The outer 2 are obvious, you've coded them explicitly. But stepping through the code will reveal the looping being done at `Words.Contains`. The Linq query is also an abstracted loop. And `wordToAdd.Lines.Contains` is also going to be a loop. You're going to pay a high price for these.

Profiling will always help. But I would suggest perhaps changing `Words` to some sort of `IDictionary<string, Word>`, where you can replace

```
if (Words.Contains(w, new WordComparer())) //Set already contains the word
{
    Word wordToAdd = (from wors in Words where wors.WordStr.ToLower() == w.WordStr.ToLower() select wors).First();
```

With something more like

```
if (Words.ContainsKey(w.WordStr))
{
    Word wordToAdd = Words[w.WordStr];
    // ...
}
```

And you could also change `Lines` into a `HashSet<Line>` instead of a list. That should improve the performance of

```
if (!wordToAdd.Lines.Contains(line))
    wordToAdd.Lines.Add(line);
```

In fact, `HashSet<T>.Add(T val)` could be used by itself, without the call to `Contains`, as `Add` returns a `bool` indicating if the addition could be performed. If a matching value is already in the set, it simply returns `false` without modifying its contents.

Try these changes, measure the performance before and after and see where you are.

Unrelated, but I also recommend that you wrap your `StreamReader` in a `using () { }` block so that the resource is properly disposed when you're through with it.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  The same file actually indexes almost instantly now (after implementing your two changes).

Comment: @Pete, that's a pretty good boost! Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to not speculate or make assumptions when it comes to performance. Grab a profiler and get some real data so you can make the correct decisions based on that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure of how to "grab a profiler".  I was really hoping someone could see something that could be improved.

Comment: @Pete: Google is your friend.

Comment: JetBrains (ReSharper guys) make one here: http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ Also - Visual Studio 2010 Premium has one built in.